# Transmission Lines voltage as a function of position and time equation

Tags: transmission-line

[image]

I am having trouble with part d. How are we supposed to determine v(z,t) if we are not given the length of the wire. I am getting (phase constant) * length = infinity, so then V0+ is zero. Where V0+ is the complex constant given by the boundary constraints of the transmission line.

Comment: Please show your attempt at part d using the transmission line equation.

Comment: Regard your notes (Lecture #2, Part A) as an example. It is now posted in the LECTURES folder. As mentioned in class, this example was an old exam problem with solution. It concerns the LODE of the wave equation, with an associated standing-wave pattern.

Comment: Answer is a function of z.

Answer (score 1):

> How are we supposed to determine v(z,t) if we are not given the length of the wire.

The problem specifies "...assuming only a forward wave from the input...".

This means either the line is infinitely long, or is terminated with a perfectly matched load. In either case, it means the answer doesn't depend on the length of the line.